# iOS release firebase

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-authentication, xcode8

I am using firebase auth in my flutter app.Is there any key/certificate needed for iOS app release just like sha1/sha256 in Android release. If yes then provide step details please.

I googled but not found any relevant answer.